# Documenter.jl: @autodocs for specific source files

Tags: julia

From Documenter.jl's documentation of [`@autodocs`](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/syntax/#@autodocs-block-1):

> [...], a **Pages** vector may be included in @autodocs to filter
>   docstrings based on the source file in which they are defined:
>
> ````
> ```@autodocs
> Modules = [Foo]
> Pages   = ["a.jl", "b.jl"]
> ```
> ````

However, it also says

> Note that page matching is done using the end of the provided strings
>   and so a.jl will be matched by **any source file that ends in a.jl**, i.e.
>   src/a.jl or src/foo/a.jl.

How can I restrict the `@autodocs` block to specific source files?

My package's source code is organized as

```
src/
    foo/a.jl
    foo/b.jl
    ignore/a.jl
    ignore/b.jl
    other.jl
```

How to make the `@autodocs` block only consider files `src/foo/a.jl` and `src/foo/b.jl` but not `src/ignore/a.jl` and `src/ignore/b.jl`?

Unfortunately, `Pages = ["foo/a.jl", "foo/b.jl"]` didn't do it for me.

Thanks in advance.

x-ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/documenter-jl-autodocs-for-specific-source-files/8784

x-ref: https://github.com/JuliaDocs/Documenter.jl/issues/630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this is a Windows issue due to absence of normalization of path separators (see linked github issue).

On Linux `Pages = ["foo/a.jl", "foo/b.jl"]` should work.

On Windows `Pages = ["foo\\a.jl", "foo\\b.jl"]` should work.

EDIT: `joinpath.("foo", ["a.jl", "b.jl"])` should work on any OS.